# Returning related field [Laravel 4]

Tags: php, laravel-4, relationship, laravel-blade, belongs-to

I have 2 models like this:

```
class Task extends Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function task() {
        return $this->hasMany('Task');
    }
}
```

..and a blade index section that looks like this:

```
@foreach ($tasks as $task)

    {{ "<tr><td>$task->user->fullname</td></tr>" }}

@endforeach
```

...but instead of returning the full name, it is returning the whole JSON object like...

```
{"id":9,"email":"FunkB@example.com","fullname":"Brycen Funk","created_at":"2014-09-09 16:40:31","updated_at":"2014-09-09 16:40:31"}->fullname
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?  I apologize in advance, because I am sure the answer is obvious and right before my eyes.

Thanks.

Dan

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add proper formatting for your code blocks (the models at the beginning and the JSON) ? It's not that hard, just select your code and click on the `{}` brackets icon in the editor's tool bar (or alternatively, indent all your code by 4 spaces in your favorite text editor before copy/pasting here). Thanks !

Comment: Does `$task->user()->fullname` make a difference? Also, are you eager loading the Users when collecting the Tasks?

Comment: I am in the process of learning laravel, so not sure if I am implementing eager loading or not.  However, $task->user()->fullname does not work.

Answer (score 0):

When your grabbing your Tasks from the DB using Eloquent, are you eager loading the User along with them? If not, to do this you'll just need to do something along these lines:

```
$tasks = Task::with(['user'])->get();
```

or alternatively you can do this within your foreach loop:

```
@foreach ($tasks as $task)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $task->user()->fullname }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: The eager loading of the user worked, I was able to echo out the $task with the user info.  However, still not able to reference the fullname as indicated.

Comment: How about setting the `protected $attributes = array('fullname');` property on you User model? @DanielDunning

Comment: Unfrtunately, that did not resolve the issue.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, at the end of the day, I created a users array that I passed to the View with the tasks array, and displayed the full name based on the index.  I know that this is not the most efficient or best practice, but got me over the hump.  Once I get better with the software, I will go back and implement a more elegant solution.